# Android application, server connection

Tags: network-programming

I have a back end application on grails that runs into my PC and I want to access to its information throuw my mobile, I used a Rest web server for connection.
I tested the connection using an emulator on my PC, I acceeded to the application using the ip adress 10.0.2.2 and it worked
but I did not find how to do it using my mobile, I tried my IP local adresse cause my mobile is connected to the same wifi network as my pc, but it did not work.
Any ideas? what ip adresse can I use in this case and how to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is an issue network option, I tried in a public wifi network and it worked.
I found out that sharing option was deactivated in my PC so I activate them but still it did not work :(